# Open a form on a record with the current month Access

Tags: forms, ms-access, records

I have been looking around and messing about with it for a bit but I can not work out how to make an MS Access form open to a record with the current month.

What I want to happen is that when the form is opened the user is sent straight to the current month of records, but without filtering only the current month.

Can anyone help? This is beyond me.

Comment: You can try set the **current record** to the key id with the date you wish. You can try to mimic the search bar in VBA to find the date you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach uses `SearchForRecord` method:

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
DoCmd.SearchForRecord , , acFirst, "Year([YourDateField]) = Year(Date()) And 
Month([YourDateField]) = Month(Date())"
End Sub
```

Alternate criteria structures:

```
DoCmd.SearchForRecord , , acFirst, "Val(Year([YourDateField]) & Month([YourDateField])) = Val(Year(Date()) & Month(Date()))"

DoCmd.SearchForRecord , , acFirst, "Val(Format([YourDateField], 'yyyymm')) = Val(Format(Date(), 'yyyymm'))"
```

Comment: This does work to a point, however my database has multiple years in it so that needs to be factored in.

However this is a great starting point. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, I usually consider year in criteria. Sorry overlooked. Thanks for fixing. Further edited answer for more info.